# Multiple textures on a surface - transparency problems

Tags: texturing, materials, transparency

I'm trying to mix two textures for a large environment scene. The base texture is a JPEG (opaque), seamless and tiled. The second texture is a PNG with transparency (using it to give variety to the background hills). I've mixed the PNG over the tiled JPEG texture using the PNG alpha as the factor.. but the rendered result has problems (when I add a black background layer in photoshop it appears correctly)

[image]

This is the node setup. 
[image]

EDIT: This node setup is actually correct... problem arose from having a second incorrect material on the same surface.

Comment: I think the mix shader inputs are inverted

Comment: Worked it out, that node setup is correct... problem was I had a duplicate material on the same surface with an incorrect node setup. :( Annoying spending so much time trying to figure out something so simple. Haha

Comment: should I delete this question now?

Comment: no... all is users experience here. You should keep the question. But decision is yours at the end.

Answer (score 1):

Ah silly me, this node setup actually gives the correct results. The problem was that I had another material slot on the same surface which had an older incorrect transparency node setup (which was causing these problems)...

Here's a render with the above node setup showing no transparency issues!
[image]